# Facebook Connect Class with Singleton : Access token issue

Tags: objective-c, facebook, singleton, access-token

I have created a singleton class called "LoginFacebook" which is meant to connect user to Facebook and to perform the different request. The problem is that I get an error about the access_token. Here it is :

```
3 : <CFString 0x4c552f0 [0xe50400]>{contents = "message"} = <CFString 0x4c55250 [0xe50400]>{contents = "An active access token must be used to query information about the current user."}
```

First I connect to Facebook by making the following request from another View Controller :

```
[[LoginFacebook loginFacebook] launchFacebook:self]
```

Then I make that second request from the same other View Controller but from another method :

```
[[LoginFacebook loginFacebook] requireName:self]
```

Here is my singleton class "LoginFacebook" :

```
LoginFacebook.h :

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "LoginFacebook.h"

@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController {

}

-(IBAction)performConnect:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)performName:(id)sender;

@end
```

LoginFacebook.m :

```
#import "LoginFacebook.h"
static LoginFacebook *loginFacebook = nil;

@implementation LoginFacebook
@synthesize name;
@synthesize facebook;

-(void)launchFacebook:(id)sender
{ 

permissions =  [[NSArray arrayWithObjects:
@"read_stream", @"publish_stream", @"offline_access",nil] retain];

Facebook* facebookbis = [[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:@"168938499825684"];
facebook = facebookbis;
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
if ([defaults objectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"]
&& [defaults objectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"]) {
facebook.accessToken = [defaults objectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
facebook.expirationDate = [defaults objectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];
}
if (![facebook isSessionValid]) {
[facebook authorize:nil delegate:self];
}
}

-(NSString *)requireName:(id)sender
{
NSLog(@"requireName asked");
[facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me" andDelegate:self];
return name;
NSLog(@"%@",[facebook accessToken]);
}


+ (LoginFacebook *)loginFacebook
{
if (loginFacebook == nil) {
loginFacebook = [[super allocWithZone:NULL] init];
}
return loginFacebook;
}

+ (id)allocWithZone:(NSZone *)zone {
return [[self loginFacebook] retain];
}

- (id)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone {
return self;
}

- (id)retain {
return self;
}

- (NSUInteger)retainCount {
return NSUIntegerMax;  //denotes an object that cannot be released
}

- (void)release {
//do nothing
}

- (id)autorelease {
return self;
}

// FBRequestDelegate

/**
* Called when the Facebook API request has returned a response. This callback
* gives you access to the raw response. It's called before
* (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didLoad:(id)result,
* which is passed the parsed response object.
*/
- (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
NSLog(@"received response");
}

/**
* Called when a request returns and its response has been parsed into
* an object. The resulting object may be a dictionary, an array, a string,
* or a number, depending on the format of the API response. If you need access
* to the raw response, use:
*
* (void)request:(FBRequest *)request
*      didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
*/
- (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didLoad:(id)result {
if ([result isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
result = [result objectAtIndex:0];
}
name = [result objectForKey:@"name"];
NSLog(@"request didLoad");
};

/**
* Called when an error prevents the Facebook API request from completing
* successfully.
*/
- (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
name = [error localizedDescription];
NSLog(@"----request didFailWithError");
NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
NSLog(@"%@", [error description]);
};


////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// FBDialogDelegate

/**
* Called when a UIServer Dialog successfully return.
*/
- (void)dialogDidComplete:(FBDialog *)dialog {
name = @"publish successfully";
}

@end
```

Please also note that I added the following method (with the corresponding FacebookLogin *facebook in the .h) to my App Delegate :

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url {

return [facebook handleOpenURL:url];
}
```

Does one of you know what is going wrong there ? I have been struggling with the code for 2 days now...

Answer (score 2):

From the error message it seems your access token isn't valid anymore or you didn't even have an access token yet. Does your app actually open a web browser the first time a user is trying to access Facebook? If not, then you probably failed to configure the project properly.

Perhaps it'd be a good idea to share the code of my Facebook singleton - I believe the code is pretty clean and easy to understand & expand. Since my needs are currently very modest I only have a method to authorize (login) and another method to post to wall. I'm using a stack so I can perform some operations in the correct order (for example login before posting message to wall, if user isn't logged in yet).

**SDFacebookController.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "FBConnect.h"

@interface SDFacebookController : NSObject 
   <FBSessionDelegate, 
   FBRequestDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, retain) Facebook *facebook;

+ (SDFacebookController *)sharedController;
- (void)authorize;
- (void)postMessageToWall:(NSString *)message;
@end
```

**SDFacebookController.m**

```
#import "SDFacebookController.h"
#import "Constants+Macros.h"
#import "SDOperationStack.h"


@interface SDFacebookController ()
@property (nonatomic, retain) SDOperationStack *operationStack;
- (void)performAuthorization;
- (void)performPostMessageToWall:(NSString *)message;
- (void)runOperation;
@end


@implementation SDFacebookController
@synthesize facebook, operationStack;

#pragma mark - Instance methods

- (void)authorize
{
   NSInvocationOperation *operation = [[[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(performAuthorization) object:nil] autorelease];
   [operationStack push:operation];

   [self runOperation];
}

- (void)postMessageToWall:(NSString *)message 
{   
   NSInvocationOperation *operation = [[[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(performPostMessageToWall:) object:message] autorelease];
   [operationStack push:operation];

   if (![facebook isSessionValid])
   {
      NSInvocationOperation *operation = [[[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(performAuthorization) object:nil] autorelease];
      [operationStack push:operation];
   }

   [self runOperation];
}

#pragma mark - Private methods 

- (void)runOperation
{
   NSOperation *operation = [operationStack pop];
   [[NSOperationQueue currentQueue] addOperation:operation];
}

- (void)performAuthorization
{
   if (![facebook isSessionValid]) 
   {
      NSArray *permissions = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"publish_stream"];
      [facebook authorize:permissions delegate:self];
   }
}

- (void)performPostMessageToWall:(NSString *)message 
{
   NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:message, @"message", nil];
   [facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/feed" andParams:params andHttpMethod:@"POST" andDelegate:self];
}

#pragma mark - FBRequestDelegate

/**
 * Called just before the request is sent to the server.
 */
- (void)requestLoading:(FBRequest *)request
{
   DLog(@"%@", request);
}

/**
 * Called when the server responds and begins to send back data.
 */
- (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
   DLog(@"%@ %@", request, response);
}

/**
 * Called when an error prevents the request from completing successfully.
 */
- (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
   DLog(@"%@ %@", request, error);

   [[[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Error", nil) 
                                message:[error localizedDescription] 
                               delegate:nil 
                      cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"OK", nil) 
                      otherButtonTitles:nil] 
     autorelease] show];

   [operationStack empty];
}

/**
 * Called when a request returns and its response has been parsed into
 * an object.
 *
 * The resulting object may be a dictionary, an array, a string, or a number,
 * depending on thee format of the API response.
 */
- (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didLoad:(id)result
{
   DLog(@"%@ %@", request, result);

   if ([operationStack isEmpty] == NO)
      [self runOperation];
   else if ([operationStack.lastOperation.invocation selector] == @selector(performPostMessageToWall:))
      [[[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"MessagePosted", nil) 
                                   message:NSLocalizedString(@"Successfully posted message on Facebook.", nil) 
                                  delegate:nil 
                         cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"OK", nil) 
                         otherButtonTitles:nil] 
        autorelease] show];
}

/**
 * Called when a request returns a response.
 *
 * The result object is the raw response from the server of type NSData
 */
- (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didLoadRawResponse:(NSData *)data
{
   DLog(@"%@ %@", request, data);
}

#pragma mark - FBSessionDelegate

/**
 * Called when the user successfully logged in.
 */
- (void)fbDidLogin 
{
   NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
   [defaults setObject:[facebook accessToken] forKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
   [defaults setObject:[facebook expirationDate] forKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];
   [defaults synchronize];
}

/**
 * Called when the user dismissed the dialog without logging in.
 */
- (void)fbDidNotLogin:(BOOL)cancelled
{

}

/**
 * Called when the user logged out.
 */
- (void)fbDidLogout
{

}

#pragma mark - Memory management 

- (id)init 
{
   self = [super init];
   if (self)
   {      
      facebook = [[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:kFacebookAppIdentifier];
      operationStack = [[SDOperationStack alloc] init];

      NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
      if ([defaults objectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"] && [defaults objectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"]) 
      {
         facebook.accessToken = [defaults objectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
         facebook.expirationDate = [defaults objectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];
      }
   }
   return self;
}

- (void)dealloc 
{
   [operationStack release];
   [facebook release];
   [super dealloc];
}

#pragma mark - Singleton

+ (SDFacebookController *)sharedController
{
   static SDFacebookController *controller = nil;

   static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
   dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
      controller = [[self alloc] init];
   });

   return controller;   
}

@end
```

**SDOperationStack.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface SDOperationStack : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSInvocationOperation *lastOperation;

- (void)push:(NSOperation *)operation;
- (NSOperation *)pop;
- (BOOL)isEmpty;
- (void)empty;

@end
```

**SDOperationStack.m**

```
#import "SDOperationStack.h"


@interface SDOperationStack ()
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *array;
@end


@implementation SDOperationStack
@synthesize array, lastOperation;

- (void)dealloc 
{
   [lastOperation release];
   [array release];
   [super dealloc];
}

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) 
    {
       array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)push:(NSInvocationOperation *)operation
{
   [array addObject:operation];
}

- (NSInvocationOperation *)pop
{
   if ([self isEmpty]) 
        return nil;

   self.lastOperation = (NSInvocationOperation *)[array lastObject];
   [array removeLastObject];
   return lastOperation;
}

- (BOOL)isEmpty 
{
   return [array count] == 0;
}

- (void)empty 
{
   [array removeAllObjects];
}

@end
```

Comment: I finally managed to get it.
The problem is that the FBRequestDelegate is to be implemented in the ViewController class which will send the request to the singleton.

You can use the really comprehensive tutorial from Barry http://barrycenter.com/BAM!coding/2011/07/simplifying-facebook-ios-sdk/

Thanks for your time Wolfgang Schreurs !